# How to measure data stored by 1 client in a SaaS database

Tags: size, azure-sql-database, saas

I have a multi tenant database for my SaaS web application. I want to set a limit of 10GB data storage per Client. How do I enforce this limit in SQL Azure. I see a lot of SaaS companies putting such limits, but how to measure how much storage 1 client has consumed in the database?

Tx

Answer (score 1):

One option to isolate the data is to have a separate schema per tenant.  And you can measure the size of the schema using below script.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
declare @SourceDB sysname
DECLARE @sql nvarchar (4000)

IF @SourceDB IS NULL BEGIN
    SET @SourceDB = DB_NAME () -- The current DB 
END


CREATE TABLE #Tables (  [schema] sysname
                      , TabName sysname )

SELECT @sql = 'insert #tables ([schema], [TabName]) 
                  select TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME 
                  from ['+ @SourceDB +'].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                      where TABLE_TYPE = ''BASE TABLE'''
EXEC (@sql)


---------------------------------------------------------------
-- #TabSpaceTxt Holds the results of sp_spaceused. 
-- It Doesn't have Schema Info!
CREATE TABLE #TabSpaceTxt (
                         TabName sysname
                       , [Rows] varchar (11)
                       , Reserved varchar (18)
                       , Data varchar (18)
                       , Index_Size varchar ( 18 )
                       , Unused varchar ( 18 )
                       )

---------------------------------------------------------------
-- The result table, with numeric results and Schema name.
CREATE TABLE #TabSpace ( [Schema] sysname
                       , TabName sysname
                       , [Rows] bigint
                       , ReservedMB numeric(18,3)
                       , DataMB numeric(18,3)
                       , Index_SizeMB numeric(18,3)
                       , UnusedMB numeric(18,3)
                       )

DECLARE @Tab sysname -- table name
      , @Sch sysname -- owner,schema

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [SCHEMA], TabNAME 
         FROM #tables

OPEN TableCursor;
FETCH TableCursor into @Sch, @Tab;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    SELECT @sql = 'exec [' + @SourceDB 
       + ']..sp_executesql N''insert #TabSpaceTxt exec sp_spaceused '
       + '''''[' + @Sch + '].[' + @Tab + ']' + '''''''';

    Delete from #TabSpaceTxt; -- Stores 1 result at a time
    EXEC (@sql);

    INSERT INTO #TabSpace
    SELECT @Sch
         , [TabName]
         , convert(bigint, rows)
         , convert(numeric(18,3), convert(numeric(18,3), 
                left(reserved, len(reserved)-3)) / 1024.0) 
                ReservedMB
         , convert(numeric(18,3), convert(numeric(18,3), 
                left(data, len(data)-3)) / 1024.0) DataMB
         , convert(numeric(18,3), convert(numeric(18,3), 
                left(index_size, len(index_size)-3)) / 1024.0) 
                 Index_SizeMB
         , convert(numeric(18,3), convert(numeric(18,3), 
                left(unused, len([Unused])-3)) / 1024.0) 
                [UnusedMB]
        FROM #TabSpaceTxt;

    FETCH TableCursor into @Sch, @Tab;
END;

CLOSE TableCursor;
DEALLOCATE TableCursor;


select [SCHEMA],SUM(ReservedMB)SizeInMB from #TabSpace
group by [SCHEMA]
```

Comment: In addition to Alberto's answer. It is currently not possible to limit the amount of memory assigned to one particular client (user in the SQL terminology) on a given database.